# How can I combine one file's tail with another's head?

Tags: linux, shell

I know how to take e.g the first 2 lines from a .txt data and appending it to the end of a .txt data. But how should I add the last 2 lines of a .txt data to the 1st line of a .txt data

I've tried :

```
tail -n 2 test1.txt >> head test1.txt # takes last 2 lines of text and adding 
                                      it to the head
```

Looks awfully wrong but I can't find the answer anywhere, doing it with tail and head.

```
tail n 2 test1.txt >> head test1.txt
cat test1.txt
```

Someone please correct my code so I get my expected result.

Comment: You could do something like: `(tail -n 2 test1.txt && cat test1.txt) >> test.tmp.txt && mv test.tmp.txt test1.txt`

Comment: The title should not just describe *what the question is about*, but describe *the question itself*, so someone else can tell if its answer will be helpful to their own problem. I've tried to edit towards that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the two commands one after the other -- the stdout resulting from doing so will be exactly the same as what you'd get by concatenating their output together, without needing to do an explicit/extra concatenation step:

```
tail -n 2 test1.txt
head -n 1 test1.txt
```

If you want to redirect their output together, put them in a brace group:

```
{
  tail -n 2 test1.txt
  head -n 1 test1.txt
} >out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
file 1 line 1
file 1 line 2
file 1 line 3
file 1 line 4
$ cat file2.txt 
file 2 line 1
file 2 line 2
file 2 line 3
file 2 line 4
$ tail -n 2 file1.txt > output.txt
$ head -n 1 file2.txt >> output.txt 
$ cat output.txt 
file 1 line 3
file 1 line 4
file 2 line 1
```